# Redirect user to next page in OAUTH

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0

I have this website created by GAS.

Login credentials will be the user's gmail account. 
It works fine when logging in my gmail but it won't get redirect to next page.

how can I do that? I'm new at using this oauth thing.

[Here's my simple website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IVph.png)

Here's my HTML code:

```js
  <script>
    
      function signOut() {
        var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        auth2.signOut().then(function () {
          console.log('User signed out.');
        });
      }
      
      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
        console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
        console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
      }

    </script>
```

```css
<style>
.wrapper{
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
}
.g-signin2{
  width: 100%;
}

.g-signin2 > div{
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0 auto;
}
body {
      background-color: white;
    }
    h1{
      color: white;
      font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
      font-weight: 500;

    }
    h3{
      color: white;
      font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
      font-weight: 100;

    }
    .center{
      margin-top: 10%;
      text-align:center;
    }
.container{
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-bottom: auto;
}
</style>
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="CLIENT-ID">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="wrapper"></div>
 <div class="container">
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" 
      -theme="light" data-width="300" data-height="50"
      data-longtitle="true">button</div><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="signOut();" style="color:black;">Sign out</a>
  </div>
```

Also, once the user has been redirected to the next page it will also display his/her information like: Full Name, Avatar Image, Gender, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to redirect to the next page you can use `window.location.href = "nextPage.html";`. If you are going to use this as a login method then you will need to send a request to your backend that verifies the token using the Google Auth Library/API. Verifying this token will produce fullname, email etc.

This can all be found in the Google OAuth docs [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth)

Comment: This does not answer the part where he will be displaying the contents from the Identity Token.

Comment: @Matt Davis, I was gonna use this as a login page. Where should I put that code? I've tried putting it on the end of the script and after I refreshed the page, it keeps on refreshing over and over again.